# Change Time of setInterval on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if it is possible to change the interval time of a `setIinterval` on the click of a button. The problem I'm currently having is that `setInterval`, which refreshes the table and ruins the effect of changing button on it.

I would like to know if this can be changed, and would appreciate your help.

---

This is the function with setInterval:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"php/recibeDos.php",
    cache:false,
    success:function(html){ 
        $("#pizarra").html(html); 

    }
});
setInterval(refresh_table, 3000);   

$("#edit-trigger").on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("btn btn-editar");
    $(this).toggleClass("btn btn-default");
    $( ".btnBorrar" ).toggle(150);
    $('.edita-paciente').toggle(250);
});
```

Comment: Iti s not a good idea to use interval on Ajax. Instead use setTimeout in the success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `clearInterval(tId)` (but first assign an id to the interval like this: `var tId = setInterval(refresh_table, 3000);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the interval time.
However, maybe you could make a function, which cancel the current interval and creates new one with the desired parameters.

setInterval returns the intervalId, which you must give as parameter to clearInterval() -function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#Return_value